# Create VERTICAL spaces under each link in a navigation menu?

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, sidebar

I am making a website with a navigation menu on the left side and I want to create space UNDER each link because right now the links are lying too close to each other and no googling help because all the solutions are for links that lie NEXT TO each other but my menu is like a LIST so I need VERTICAL space, space UNDER each link not next to each link !!! Thank you in advance.

PLEASE EXPLAIN WELL I AM VERY NEW AT THIS.

CODES:

```
<aside>
<nav> 
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#.html" class="button">NAME</a></li>
<li>
<a href="#.html" class="button">NAME</a></li>
<li>
<a href="#.html" class="button">NAME</a></li>
<li>
<a href="#.html" class="button">NAME</a></li>
<li>
<a href="#.html" class="button">NAME</a></li>
<li>
<a href="#.html" class="button">NAME</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</aside>
```

AND CSS:

```
aside {
    overflow:hidden;
    display: inline-block; 
    background-color: #E3D6C8;

}
nav ul  {
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav {
    float: left; 
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 130px; 
    padding-right: 35px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
a.button,div.container {
    float:left;
}
a.button {
    background-color: #FFB000;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your code

Comment: why screenshot, put code

Comment: <aside>
<nav> 
<ul>
<li>
<a href=".html" class="button">#</a></li>
<li>
<a href=".html" class="button">#</a></li>
<li>
<a href=".html" class="button">#</a></li>
<li>
<a href=".html" class="button">#</a></li>
<li>
<a href=".html" class="button">#</a></li>
<li>
<a href=".html" class="button">#</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

Comment: and what difference does it make you see it in the screenshots you see what to do

Comment: the difference is that we cannot manipulate code inside screenshot :) so you mean that we have to re-write the code ourself and make changes ... i think you should at least do this effort so that we can help, no ? :)

Comment: Okay I have added it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To drop the link down further you can put padding between each of the links. 
Here is the way to do it with padding:

```css
aside {
    overflow:hidden;
    display: inline-block; 
    background-color: #E3D6C8;

}
nav ul  {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li  {
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
}
nav {
    float: left; 
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 130px; 
    padding-right: 35px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
a.button,div.container {
    float:left;
}
a.button {
    background-color: #FFB000;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
```

```html
<aside>
  <nav> 
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#.html" class="button">NAME</a></li><br/>
      <li>
        <a href="#.html" class="button">NAME</a></li><br/>
      <li>
        <a href="#.html" class="button">NAME</a></li><br/>
      <li>
        <a href="#.html" class="button">NAME</a></li><br/>
      <li>
        <a href="#.html" class="button">NAME</a></li><br/>
      <li>
        <a href="#.html" class="button">NAME</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

If you want more or less space between the top and bottom change the number 15 to whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you but how do I add it between each link I do that in css right to keep css code from html code so I need a name for every link like a div around each link?

Comment: I hadn't realized that it wasn't working between each link. For me it had. I would recommend padding. I altered my answer to best fit what you need. Sorry it did not work the first time.